# psql script execution not returning error

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to execute multiple sql scripts using psql. I created one master script with all the scripts to be executed as below. I want all the scripts to succeed or fail together.

```
master.sql

    BEGIN;
    \i one.sql
    \i two.sql
    \i three.sql
    COMMIT;
```

I am trying to catch the error code of psql to determine if it success. When i query for ?$ it always returns 0. I figured when add ON_ERROR_STOP=1 to command it returns proper error code. Problem with this approach if the error happens in three.sql it does not roll back one.sql and two.sql transactions.

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost -d test -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -f master.sql
```

What would be correct approach to find out if script executed successfully.

Comment: If one of the prior scripts contains a `COMMIT`, that cannot be rolled back.

Comment: None of the individual scripts have Commit present yet when there is an error transaction does not rollback.

Comment: Oh yes, it will. There must be something in your scripts that you missed.